# React bootstrap warnings for components that weren't imported

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap, react-typescript

I get a slew of React bootstrap warnings in my console whenever I run my application. Here is just a few:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/index.js 70:0-79
"export 'ThemeProviderProps' was not found in './ThemeProvider'
 @ ./src/Components/Header.tsx
 @ ./src/App.tsx
 @ ./src/index.tsx

WARNING in ./node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/index.js 73:0-73
"export 'ToastHeaderProps' was not found in './ToastHeader'
 @ ./src/Components/Header.tsx
 @ ./src/App.tsx
 @ ./src/index.tsx

WARNING in ./node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/index.js 71:0-55
"export 'ToastProps' was not found in './Toast'
 @ ./src/Components/Header.tsx
 @ ./src/App.tsx
 @ ./src/index.tsx

WARNING in ./node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/index.js 75:0-142
"export 'ToggleButtonCheckboxProps' was not found in './ToggleButtonGroup'
 @ ./src/Components/Header.tsx
 @ ./src/App.tsx
 @ ./src/index.tsx

WARNING in ./node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/index.js 75:0-142
"export 'ToggleButtonGroupProps' was not found in './ToggleButtonGroup'
 @ ./src/Components/Header.tsx
 @ ./src/App.tsx
 @ ./src/index.tsx

WARNING in ./node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/index.js 74:0-76
"export 'ToggleButtonProps' was not found in './ToggleButton'
 @ ./src/Components/Header.tsx
 @ ./src/App.tsx
 @ ./src/index.tsx

WARNING in ./node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/index.js 75:0-142
"export 'ToggleButtonRadioProps' was not found in './ToggleButtonGroup'
 @ ./src/Components/Header.tsx
 @ ./src/App.tsx
 @ ./src/index.tsx

WARNING in ./node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/index.js 76:0-61
"export 'TooltipProps' was not found in './Tooltip'
 @ ./src/Components/Header.tsx
 @ ./src/App.tsx
 @ ./src/index.tsx
```

Here is my `Header.tsx` file for reference:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Row, Image, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import logo from '../assets/mylogo.png';
import './Header.scss';

export class Header extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="app-header">
                <Row className="app-header-content">
                    <Col className="col-1">
                        <Image className="logo" src={logo}></Image>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Seems fairly innocuous. I'm not quite sure what the warnings are supposed to indicate.

Any help?

Comment: You are missing type declarations for `react-bootstrap` or some other library or they are out of date `npm i @types/react-bootstrap` and make sure everything is up to date

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. If you want to write this as an answer, I'll accept it.